# Python client refuses to connect to my SocketServer server

Tags: python, client

*Hello,*

*I have a problem , I have a python server creates with SocketServer ( I learn ) , this one apparently works , but when I want to connect with my client I get a traceback , I really do not understand . Allow me to share code of the server, the client, telnet and traceback*

**server code:**

```
import SocketServer 
import threading


class EchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "{} is connected".format(self.client_address)
        data = "test"
        while len(data):
            data=self.request.recv(1024)
            print "Client sent: {}".format(data)
            self.request.send(data)

        print "Client is gone"


server_Addr = "127.0.0.1"
server_port = 7008
print "Running Server on address {} and port        {}".format(server_Addr,server_port)
server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer((server_Addr,server_port), EchoHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

**client code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 7008
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

**the traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/labofx/Bureau/client_script_v6.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

**the telnet output to show that the server is working**

```
labofx@labofx-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 7008 Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to 127.0.0.1. Escape character is '^]'. hello hello

and the output of the server:

Running Server on address 127.0.0.1 and port 7008 ('127.0.0.1', 50825) is connected Client sent: hello
```

PS: sorry for my bad English I am native French speaking

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: this is a new post , the old one was deleted , cause it was not clear enough, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: It actually work `('127.0.0.1', 57107) is connected
Client sent: Hello, World!
Client sent: 
Client is gone`

Comment: I have found how to make it work. The client need to be executed through the terminal,  the error comes only when i run it through the file with run module

Answer (score 0):

thank you Chaker ^^

With your comment ,I have found how to make it work. The client need to be executed through the terminal, the error comes only when i run it through the file with run module.